# For $0<x<y<1$，prove that $\frac{x^x+y^y}{x^y+y^x}<\sqrt{\frac{y}{x}}.$

Tags: inequality

I only prove that for $0<x<y\leq 1/2$ the result is right as following:
the inequality is equivalent to
$$x^{2x+1}+2x^{x+1}y^y+x y^{2y}<y x^{2y}+2y^{x+1}x^y+y^{2x+1}.$$

First, $x^{2x+1}<y^{2x+1}$ because of $$\left(\frac{y}{x}\right)^{2x+1}>1;$$

Second, $2x^{x+1}y^y<2y^{x+1}x^y$ because of
$$\frac{2y^{x+1}x^y}{2x^{x+1}y^y}=\left(\frac{y}{x}\right)^{x+1-y}>1;$$

Last, for $0<x<y\leq 1/2$,
$xy^{2y}<yx^{2y}$ because of
$$\frac{yx^{2y}}{xy^{2y}}=\left(\frac{y}{x}\right)^{1-2y}\geq 1.$$

Comment: and what is in the other case?

Comment: I do not know the other case, so any help will be welcome !!! May be my method is only useful in this case!

Answer (score 2):

$$\frac{x^x+y^y}{x^y+y^x}<\frac{x^x+y^y}{2\sqrt{x^yy^x}}\ \ (\because a+b>2\sqrt{ab})$$
$$=\frac{1}{2}\left(\sqrt{\frac{x^{2x}}{x^yy^x}}+\sqrt{\frac{y^{2y}}{x^yy^x}}\right)$$
$$<\frac{1}{2}\sqrt{2}\sqrt{\frac{x^{2x}+y^{2y}}{x^yy^x}}\ \ \left(\because a+b<\sqrt{2(a^2+b^2)}\right)$$
$$<\frac{1}{2}\sqrt{2}\sqrt{\frac{2y^{2x}}{x^yy^x}}\ \ (\because0<x<y<1)$$
$$=\sqrt{\frac{y^x}{x^y}}<\sqrt{\frac{y}{x}}.$$

The last inequality is equivalent to $\frac{y^x}{x^y}<\frac{y}{x},0<x<y<1$
which is easy to prove!

Comment: After using $a+b\leq\sqrt{2(a^2+b^2)}$ it should be $\frac{1}{2}\sqrt2\sqrt{\frac{x^{4x}+y^{4y}}{x^yy^x}}$

Comment: Here I set $a=\sqrt{\frac{x^{2x}}{x^yy^x}}$ and $b=\sqrt{\frac{y^{2y}}{x^yy^x}}$. Please think carefully!!@  Michael Rozenberg

Comment: Nice proof! +1.